# ajax running error despite response being 200

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel, laravel-5

I have multiple uploads on a page, and I am workin on tidying it up, so:

Here's my js:

```
$(".img").change(function () {
        var form = $(this).closest('form');
        getPath(form);
    })
    deleteButton();
    copyGalleryData();
});

function getPath(form) {
    var name = $(form).attr('name');
    submitImage(form, name);
}
var path_to_delete;

function submitImage(form, name) {
    var url = '/image/upload';
    var form_data = new FormData($(form)[0]);
    submit(name);
    form_data.append('img', $(form).children(".img"));
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        data: form_data,
        dataType: 'json',
        async: true,
        type: 'post',
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            $(form).children('.image-container').append('<img id="image" name=' + name + '" src="' + data + '" />')
            $(".imageDelete").attr('data', data);
            alerts();
            var deleting = false;
            success(name, deleting, data);
            $('.messages').html('<div class="alert alert-success">Image Uploaded!<div>');
        },
        error: function (data) {
            alerts();
            fail();
            $('.messages').html('<div class="alert alert-danger">File type not supported! Use files with image extension only!</div>');
        },
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
    });
}
```

and controller:

```
class ImageController extends Controller
{
    use S3;
    public function upload(ImgRequest $request)
    {
        if ($request->hasFile('img')) {
            $this->imageEntity();
            return response()->json($path);
        }
        if ($request->hasFile('coverUpload')) {
            $this->imageCover();
        }
    }
    public function imageEntity()
    {
        $s3Path = config('app.path', public_path());
        $image = Input::file('img');
        Log::info('Retrieving Image', ['image' => $image]);
        $filePath = 'public/logo/' . time() . '.' . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $path = $s3Path . $filePath;
        $this->S3Store($filePath, $image);
        $session = session()->get('key');
        try {
            $update_image = Entity::find($session);
            $update_image->logo = $path;
            $update_image->save();
            Log::info('Succesfully saved logo for', ['entity_id' => $session]);
            return response()->json($path);
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            Log::error('Images:', ['message' =>$e->getMessage(), 'entity_id' => $session]);
        }
    }
    public function imageCover()
    {
        $s3Path = config('app.path', public_path());
        $image = Input::file('coverUpload');
        Log::info('Retrieving Cover', ['image' => $image]);
        $filePath = 'public/cover/' . time() . '.' . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $path = $s3Path . $filePath;
        $this->S3Store($filePath, $image);
        $session = session()->get('key');
        try {
            $image = new Images;
            $image->path = $path;
            $image->cover = true;
            $image->entity_id = $session;
            $image->save();
            Log::info('Succesfully saved logo for', ['entity_id' => $session]);
            return $path;
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            Log::error('Images:', ['message' =>$e->getMessage(), 'entity_id' => $session]);
        }
    }
```

Now the funny thing is response is 200, however it is empty ($path is defined) and ajax is triggering error: part of the code and not success. I have checked the log, and try has been successful:

> [2017-10-16 11:22:01] local.INFO: Retrieving Image {"image":"[object]
>   (Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile: /tmp/phpHPchM4)"}  [2017-10-16
>   11:22:01] local.INFO: Adding to S3   [2017-10-16 11:22:05] local.INFO:
>   Succesfully added to S3   [2017-10-16 11:22:05] local.INFO:
>   Succesfully saved logo for {"entity_id":"324"}

Could anyone please help me solve this matter?

Update::

I have updated the controller so that the  function returns $path, and main function return the response, however for some reason it is saying that $path  is undefined, how to pass data from return to controller that is returned it?

Comment: any errors in your browser console? Is the response invalid, perhaps?

Comment: not really response is 200, and if i refresh page, nnew image shows up. It uploads fine

Comment: Going to the error handler after receiving a response usually means that the response could not be deserialised - ie. it's not valid JSON, although you should see a console error in that case. Could you check the response in the network tab of the console and edit your question to include it

Comment: I have included a console.log when it triggers error:  as you see response is 200 so I don't know what is wrong

Comment: Did you see my previous comment?

Comment: your function logic is a bit of a mess. $path is never defined in your "upload" method, it simply doesn't exist in that context. `imageEntity()` should just `return $path` instead of returning a JSON response object. Then the calling function (`upload()`) can receive the path variable as the return value, and use it in the repsonse it creates. i.e. `$path = $this->imageEntity();` That way, you then have $path defined within the context of the "upload" function. You perhaps need to try and understand about variable scope a bit more.

Comment: Also, since "imageEntity" isn't called directly by the browser, it shouldn't really be trying to return a JSON response directly. It's a utility function which is used by other PHP functions, so it should return a PHP variable which other code can make use of. So your mistakes were - returning a value from imageEntity which is no use to other PHP code (it can't natively read JSON) and also not making use of the returned value (even if it had been usable). It looks like you maybe need to check how you're using imageCover() as well and repeat the same pattern.

Comment: ADyson, thanks  now it works ;)0